# Why is this simple javascript program not working?

Tags: javascript, html

The alert window gives me the message NaN what is wrong?
Thanx for all the help

```
var weight = parseFloat(document.BMI.weight.value)
var height = parseFloat(document.BMI.height.value)

function calcBMI() {
var answer = weight * 703 / (height*height)
return answer;
  }
    </script>


 <form action="" name="BMI">
<input type="text" name="weight" />
<input type="text" name="height" />
<input type="submit" onclick="alert(calcBMI())" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcBMI() {
var weight = parseFloat(document.BMI.weight.value)
var height = parseFloat(document.BMI.height.value)
var answer = weight * 703 / (height*height)
return answer;
  }
    </script>


 <form action="" name="BMI">
<input type="text" name="weight" />
<input type="text" name="height" />
<input type="submit" onclick="alert(calcBMI())" />
</form>
```

Hopefully it works now :)

Comment: It does thank you so much :-) so when using functions the variables outside the function is not accessible within the function if not declared inside the function....is that right?

Comment: Yeah the DOM parses from top to bottom, when the DOM encounters the variable it is `undefined` and calling to `calcBMI` is at runtime so at that point the value present in the textbox is unknown. If its your solution then kindly mark it as answered.

Comment: The variables are still available within the function if they are declared outside of it. The problem you ran into though is that the variables were getting their values set too soon, when the text fields didn't exist yet. So when the function ran, the variables already had bad values stored in them. His example makes bit so then variables get their values at the correct time, after then function gets called and after the text boxes have been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your variables into your function call. *Edit.. I was beaten to the punch.

```
<form action="" name="BMI">
  <input type="text" name="weight" />
  <input type="text" name="height" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="alert(calcBMI())" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function calcBMI() {
    var weight = parseFloat(document.BMI.weight.value)
    var height = parseFloat(document.BMI.height.value)
    var answer = weight * 703 / (height*height)
    console.log(weight);
    return answer;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function calcBMI() {
    var weight = parseFloat(document.BMI.weight.value)
var height = parseFloat(document.BMI.height.value)
var answer = weight * 703 / (height*height)
return answer;
  }
    </script>
```

There is a problem with local and grobal variable. While you are clicking the button the function is not fetching the value from the textboxes